# How to Select * Where Everything is Distinct Except One Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, conditional-operator

I'm trying to pull 6 records using the code below but there are some cases where the information is updated and therefore it is pulling duplicate records.

My code:

```
SELECT column2, count(*) as 'Count'
FROM ServiceTable p
join HIERARCHY h
on p.LOCATION_CODE = h.LOCATION
where Report_date between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-30'


and Column1 = 'Issue '
and LOCATION = '8789'

and
( record_code = 'INCIDENT' or
    (
    SUBMIT_METHOD = 'Web' and
    not exists
    (
    select *
    from ServiceTable p2
    where p2.record_code = 'INCIDENT'
        and p2.incident_id = p.incident_id      
        )


    )
)
```

The problem is that instead of the six records it is pulling eight. I would just use distinct * but the file_date is different on the duplicate entries:

```
FILE_DATE     Incident_ID       Column1        Column2
 4/4/17          123              Issue      Service - Red
 4/4/17          123              Issue      Service - Blue
 4/5/17          123              Issue      Service - Red
 4/5/17          123              Issue      Service - Blue
```

The desired output is:

```
  COLUMN2         COUNT
 Service - Red      1
 Service - Blue     1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need any other info just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn your original select statement without the aggregation function into a subquery, you can distinct that on your values that are not the changing date, then select a COUNT from there. Don't forget your GROUP BY clause at the end.

```
SELECT Column2, COUNT(Incident_ID) AS Service_Count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Incident_ID, Column1, Column2
  FROM ServiceTable p
  JOIN HIERARCHY h ON p.LOCATION_CODE = h.LOCATION
  WHERE Report_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30'
  AND Column1 = 'Issue '
  AND LOCATION = '8789'
  AND
  ( record_code = 'INCIDENT' or
      (
      SUBMIT_METHOD = 'Web' and
      NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT *
        FROM ServiceTable p2
        WHERE p2.record_code = 'INCIDENT'
            AND p2.incident_id = p.incident_id)
      )
  )
)
GROUP BY Column2
```

Also, if you are joining tables it is a good practice to fully qualify the field you are selecting. Example: p.Column2, p.Incident_ID, h.LOCATION. That way, even your distinct fields are easier to follow where they came from and how they relate.

Finally, don't forget that COUNT is a reserved word. I modified your alias accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Sand! I think you are missing a parenthesis somewhere though?

Comment: @CoolHand Add a closing parenthesis `)` above the final `GROUP BY`, and also an alias for that derived table.  So `) A` for example, where A is the derived table alias. EDIT: Only one parenthesis, didn't see one hiding in there.

Comment: Yep, right above the GROUP BY. I edited my answer to add it in. My mistake! I don't think you will NEED to add an alias for the subquery in there in this case. Because it is selecting from a single consolidated source, you should be able to get away with just the field names. Because it is a single source, my habit is to not qualify the field names. But that's just my quirks.

Comment: @SandPiper The derived table alias is required in all versions of SQL Server afaik.  Might be different in 2016, I haven't used that yet.  You don't need to alias any of the outer column references, but you still need to name the table.  Either way, good answer.

Comment: Much appreciated SanPiper! This seems to have worked. Now if only the performance were better. When I run at the UNIT level it only takes a few seconds. When I run it for several hundred units for an overall view it takes nearly 20 minutes to run. Wonder if it is because of the not exists function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an aggregation function (count), you should use `group by` for the column **not** in the aggregation function:

```
    SELECT column2, count(*) as 'Count'
    FROM ServiceTable p
    join HIERARCHY h
    on p.LOCATION_CODE = h.LOCATION
    where Report_date between '2017-04-01' and '2017-04-30'
    and Column1 = 'Issue '
    and LOCATION = '8789'
    and
    ( record_code = 'INCIDENT' or
        (
        SUBMIT_METHOD = 'Web' and
        not exists
        (
        select *
        from ServiceTable p2
        where p2.record_code = 'INCIDENT'
            and p2.incident_id = p.incident_id      
            )


        )
    )
    group by column2
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this I just left it out of my code. Thank you though! Any thoughts on my original question on how to weed out the duplicates?

Comment: You have Report_date  in query but FILE_DATE     in column name  .. are you sure you are filter the right column?

Comment: Yes. They are two separate dates.